# Gradle dependencies: Get latest snapshot from remote repo

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am working in multiple releases. I have a module A which has version number 1.8 for Release 1. and the same module which has version number 2.1 for Release 2.

For release 1, I would like to get the latest snapshot library from nexus. Before the introduction of v2.1, if I use the 'latest.integration' which fetches the latest integration release which is 1.9-SNAPSHOT. But now it fetches 2.1 :(. For Release 1, I always need the latest integration version of 1.+ from nexus.

How can we achieve this in gradle?

Comment: Do you use the same repository for release and snapshots?

Comment: No, different repos..

Answer (score 0):

If you use `1.+` instead of `latest.integration`, you should get exactly what you want.

Comment: 1.+ fetches the latest release version i.e 1.8. But I want the latest version of the module i.e 1.9-SNAPSHOT

Comment: If I use `mavenCentral()` and `maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }` as repositories and `'org.apereo.service.persondir:person-directory-api:1.+'` as dependency string, it is correctly resolved: `org.apereo.service.persondir:person-directory-api:1.+ -> 1.8.6-SNAPSHOT`